# Prepend data in a key-value Object in php

Tags: php

I'm quite unfamiliar with php and I'm having difficults to prepend data in a key-value Object. I have this:

```
 {"5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer"}
```

I need place this at the beginning:

```
"no_job":"Please select an option"
```

So then my data need to be something like this:

```
{"no_job":"Please select an option", "5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer"}
```

I've tried with:

```
 $job_list["no_job"] = "Please select an option";
 array_unshift($job_list, $job_list["no_job"]);
```

However the option then is duplicated at the end of the Object:

```
{"no_job":"Please select an option", "5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer", "no_job":"Please select an option"}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Problem is your already adding the item into the array at `$job_list["no_job"] = "Please select an option";` as well as adding it in with the `array_unshift()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP natively understands JSON, so turn it into an array, then use `array_merge`:

```
$originalArray = json_decode('{"5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer"}', true);

$newArray = array_merge(['no_job' => 'Please select an option'], $originalArray);

print json_encode($newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add the key and value at the beginning of the string, turn your json into an associative array using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and `true` as the second parameter. Then you could use the [union](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) + operator:

```
$job_list = json_decode(' {"5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer"}
', true);
$job_list = ['no_job' => 'Please select an option'] + $job_list;
echo json_encode($job_list);
```

Result:

```
{"no_job":"Please select an option","5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer"}
```